# iText: why would adding an image cause text to appear fuzzy in PDF?

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm using iText with Java to create a PDF file. I'm trying to place a paragraph on left, and float an image on right (e.g. next to each other). Using the following code does insert the image, but it also makes the text fuzzy on the entire page (other pages are fine).

```
// add image 
Image img = Image.getInstance(imgPath);
img.setAlignment(Image.RIGHT | Image.TEXTWRAP);
img.scaleToFit(1000, 72f); // 1" height
//img.setSpacingBefore(0f);  // does not have any effect
document.add(img);  

// add text
Paragraph par = new Paragraph("some text here", styleBody);
par.setSpacingBefore(20f);
document.add(par);
```

If I remove the image portion of the code, the text looks clean. This is my first attempt at adding an image next to text. Must be doing something obviously wrong. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but if I had to guess, I'd say it's because the problem you describe can't be reproduced. I've never seen this behavior. I don't know which version of iText you're using. I don't know which PDF viewer you're using. Maybe the problem is specific to one specific viewer. Does it also occur when using Adobe Reader? Maybe it's a viewer setting (similar to "Degraded printing"). In its current state, your question is unanswerable. Maybe the down vote was meant to tell you that (but a comment explaining the down vote would have been nice).

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLowagie. I'm using Adobe Acrobat X Pro. The only thing I change is commenting out the `//add image` section of code above. When commented out, the page looks fine, and when it's present, all text on the page is fuzzy. Yet, if I print the PDF on paper, the printed text is fine. From your response, at least it's not something obvious with the code as shown, so that helps. I'll see if I can find a workaround some other way.

Comment: Provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so that other people can reproduce it. Give us a standalone example without any external dependencies (except for iText) and share the image. (Is it by any chance a WMF file?) Only if we can reproduce the problem with that example, we can start looking for the culprit. Now, we have nothing to work with. We have thousands of examples in which we add images that don't show the behavior you describe. The only valid answer we can currently give you, is *"It works for us."*

Comment: Understood, I assume it's something I'm doing rather than the framework. The image is a png file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem. The code above is perfectly fine. The problem was I was using a PNG image with transparency. When I removed the transparency (by re-exporting the image from Illustrator with transparency turned off), I was able to create PDFs with clear text.

I think the transparency forces the PDF page to be written in CMYK color scheme rather than RGB, which perhaps causes this issue.

Hope this helps someone else. I searched everywhere but couldn't find any leads talking about fuzzy text in iText.

Comment: This sounds like an issue of the pdf viewer in question (even if it's adobe Acrobat), not of itext as pdf generator in particular.